# Rust - Specifying a Lifetime Parameter for the Borrow Trait

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have a struct (`DataSource`) that holds some data (`&[u8]`), and a custom iterator that iterates over it.

```
struct DataSource<'a> {
    data: &'a Vec<u8>,
}

struct MyIterator<'a> {
    source: DataSource<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for MyIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let ret = &self.source.data[0];
        Some(ret)
    }
}
```

Notice a few important things here:

- The `Item` of the iterator has a lifetime. This is only possible because the lifetime is already used by one of the struct's fields - `source`
- The compiler is smart enough to detect that since `Item`s lifetime is `'a`, the lifetime of `ret` must also be `'a`.

Now, due to my use-case, I would like to add the following features:

- `DataSource` should also be able to own `data`.
- `data` is not `Clone`.

My initial solution was to replalce `data: &'a [u8]` with `data: D` where `D: Borrow<[u8]>`:

```
struct DataHolder<D: Borrow<[u8]>> {
    data: D,
}

struct MyIterator<D: Borrow<[u8]>> {
    holder: DataHolder<D>,
}

impl<D: Borrow<[u8]>> Iterator for MyIterator<D> {
    type Item = &u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        Some(&self.holder.data.borrow()[0])
    }
}
```

I thought this would work since due to blanket implementations both `&[u8]` and `[u8]` implement `Borrow<[u8]>`. However this doesn't compile. The iterator's item is `&u8` so it requires an explicit lifetime. `MyIterator` doesn't have any lifetimes to reference so writing `type Item = &'a u8` would result in an undeclared lifetime.

My next solution was to add phantom data and reference the lifetime through that:

```
struct DataHolder<'a, D: Borrow<[u8]>, T: 'a> {
    data: D,
    p: PhantomData<&'a T>,
}

struct MyIterator<'a, D: Borrow<[u8]>, T: 'a> {
    holder: DataHolder<'a, D, T>,
}

impl<'a, D: Borrow<[u8]>, T> Iterator for MyIterator<'a, D, T> {
    type Item = &'a u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        Some(&self.holder.data.borrow()[0])
    }
}
```

Which produces the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src\bin\main7c.rs:16:26
   |
16 |         Some(&self.holder.data.borrow()[0])
   |                                ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> src\bin\main7c.rs:15:10
   |
15 |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |             ^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src\bin\main7c.rs:16:9
   |
16 |         Some(&self.holder.data.borrow()[0])
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src\bin\main7c.rs:12:6
   |
12 | impl<'a, D: Borrow<[u8]>, T> Iterator for MyIterator<'a, D, T> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src\bin\main7c.rs:15:43
   |
15 |       fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |  ______________________________________________^
16 | |         Some(&self.holder.data.borrow()[0])
17 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: expected `<MyIterator<'a, D, T> as Iterator>`
              found `<MyIterator<'_, D, T> as Iterator>`
```

The compiler can't infer that the lifetime of the returned value must be `'a` like in the first example. I could solve this giving up on implementing `Iterator` but that would defeat the whole point of using an iterator.

```
impl<'a, D: Borrow<[u8]>, T> MyIterator<'a, D, T> {
    fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a u8> {
        Some(&self.holder.data.borrow()[0])
    }
}
```

Is there a way of solving this without giving up on the `Iterator` trait?

Comment: (Haven't read it all, but) "The compiler is smart enough to detect that since Items lifetime is `'a`, and that the mutable borrow in `&mut self` must life at least as long as the item, the lifetimes of both `&mut self` and `ret` are `'a`." What? No, no. `&mut self` has its own distinct lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way of solving this without giving up on the `Iterator` trait?

No. Suppose `D` is `Vec<u8>`. What would be the lifetime `'a`?

When it was already a reference, we could just reuse its lifetime. This is because, assuming `data` is `&'a T`, `&self.data[0]` where `self` is `&'b mut self` can be seen as (pseudo-Rust):

```rust
let slice_data_pointer: &'a u8 = (*self.data);
slice_data_pointer
```

That is, we just copy the reference.

But when `data` is owned, there is no reference to be copied. The only source of truth is `self.data` itself - and `self.data` is borrowed only for the lifetime of `self`. So you need the yielded values of iterator to depend on `next()`'s `self`. This is the classic lending/streaming iterator, and it:

- Doesn't exist in the standard library.
- Requires Generic Associated Types (which is part of the reason it is not in the standard library).
- Allows only one yielded value to exist at any time - they can't coexist, because they all borrow mutably from `self` with different lifetimes. In other words, it cannot implement operations like [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect).

However, we can learn from the way the actual `Vec` impls `Iterator`. Specifically, it doesn't - and so do owned values in general - they implement `IntoIterator` instead for a reference to them, potentially with an `iter()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to clarify, since `slice_data_pointer` cannot outlive `&'b mut self`, however must be valid for `'a`, so does that mean that `'b` lives for at least as long as `'a`?

Comment: @RoyVaron The opposite; `'a` outlives `'b`. `slice_data_pointer` _can_ outlive `&'b mut self`, since shared references are `Copy` (this is what I tried to emphasis by saying "That is, we just copy the reference."). We just copy the `&'a` reference behind the `&'b mut self`.